# run iOS app from web (angular)

Tags: ios, swift, angular

I'm developing an iOS app
i have a payment page designed by angular

user click on a payment button in ios app and i run a url page with few paramaters :

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string:"http://www.testt.com/price/personId/packageName")!)
```

price is money user has entered in textfield and package-name id the schema name i should send it to web page that runs my app (return to app with running that string) i have declared  in info.plist

then after been successful or unsuccessful payment. it should return to app by clicking on “return to app” button on web site.

actually angular runs the packageName i have sent with url like this way : http://packageName://

i tried to implement this by universal link like this way : packageName:// but wont open this link because of special chars in url.i used encoding method to encode chars but not successful because url removes the chars :// then i tried app site association method which i faced cannot parse app site association file

so i have few question for you :

1_is there any trick to run url with special chars ??
2_what would you do if you were me ??

3_i tried apple-app-site-association too but can not parse error which i have a question about this method how could this file opens my app? this way : applink:http://msite.com  ??  because it contains spacial chars in it again

excuse my awful English at the end

talk to me before voting down

update :

```
    var encodedChars="openMyApp"    //schema name

         encodedChars=encodedChars.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters:CharacterSet.alphanumerics)!


        let url="http://test.com/#/payment/\(id)/\(price!)/\(encodedChars)"


    UIApplication.shared.openURL(NSURL(string: url)! as URL)
```

angular code :

```
if (this.accounting.packageName === 'openMyApp') {
          this.url = this.accounting.packageName + '://';
        } else {
          this.url = 'http://' + this.accounting.packageName;
        }

<a class="btn btn-default" title="" href="{{url}}"></a>
```

Comment: Rather than opening the URL in safari you should open the page in your app using a `WKWebView` or `SFSafariViewController`. That way the user doesn't get "bounced" in and out of your app

Comment: test it.not working...I have problem with :// chars no matter which component I'm using webView or sfsafari

Comment: Are you url encoding any URL that you send to the web site?

Comment: update first post. have test other encoding too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have implemented **custom url scheme** for my app. If i write some thing like this

**`myappName://`**

in safari and press enter, my app is opened.

My angular + backend developer is using this line of code to open my app using custom url scheme. he is sending parameters along the scheme which i can read

```
this.document.location.href = 'myappname://appname.com/login?name='+id+'&id='+token;
```

Follow these 2 simple steps, i hope this will help you.

---

### 1.How to implement custom url schemes

[Official docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/core_app/allowing_apps_and_websites_to_link_to_your_content/communicating_with_other_apps_using_custom_urls)

[Helpful link](https://coderwall.com/p/mtjaeq/ios-custom-url-scheme)

---

### 2.How to handle custom URL scheme with params in app delegate

handle the custom url and read params in **`appDelegate`** in this function

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
  if let query = url.query {
    //that's my logic. yours url may be different
    let components = query.components(separatedBy: "=")
    print(components)
  }
```

}

let me know if you need any help

Comment: thank to replaying. my angular is using. this.document.location.href = 'myappname:// '   with http prefix but url removes : chars and lunching fails

Comment: Have you registered custom url scheme for your app ?

Comment: I have. when I type openMyApp:// manually in Safari runs my app correctly

Comment: have you  test  this.document.location.href = 'myappname://'  in your app ?without path

Comment: so you don't want to send parameters with the url ?

Comment: You want to send parameters with url OR not ?

Comment: So, you just want to open the iOS app using angular. right. 

are you using http prefix ?

Comment: i did not use http prefix. Just try this line in angular WITHOUT http prefix 

`this.document.location.href = 'myappname://appname.com`

Comment: and why and where are you using `http` prefix?

Comment: thanks you for helping me await. what is appname.com?? should I replace it with my website? or my bundle id ?

Comment: im not familial with angular but out programmer says http prefix opens android app.

Comment: dont use http prefix my bro. Make sure to match the scheme name that you registered like `schemeName://`. and your app should be opened.

Comment: ok in your angular code Just write this line for testing. 
`this.document.location.href = 'yourSchemeNameHere://`. And test.

Comment: there is something wrong here. it changes the String from : myapp://. to my app//. and won't run

Comment: Maybe you are not writing correct synax in angular. 
just type `yourSchemeNameHere://` in safari and hit enter. If you have correctly setup custom url scheme, your app should be opened from safari.

Comment: Just use this in angular, nothing else. no http nothing, just `this.document.location.href = 'yourSchemeNameHere://`. And it should work.

Comment: I will let you know if I test it.+1 for now if works mark as a correct answer